# Local storage update quantities

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i have a question
i've make this code to update my local storage, so everything work but
when i update my local storage to add quantities, for exemple if i have
already 2 couch and i add 2 more couch in my local storage the result is 22

So i think it miss some "parseInt" in my code but i don't realy know where
so please that will be greatfull if you can help me i don't really know what to do

```js
btnCart.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{


  event.preventDefault();

  function addToCart() {


    let color = colorChoice.value;
    console.log(color);
  
    let name = productName;
    console.log(name);
  
    let price = productPrice;
    console.log(price);
  
    let quantity = productQuantity.value;
    console.log(quantity);

  
    const productToAdd = {
      id : id,
      name : name,
      price : price,
      color: color,
      quantity: quantity
    };


    const currentCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(cartName)) ?? [];


    const itemIndex = currentCart.findIndex((item) =>
            item.id === productToAdd.id && item.color === productToAdd.color
    );

    if (itemIndex !== -1) {

        currentCart[itemIndex].quantity += productToAdd.quantity;
    } 
    
    else {
    
        currentCart.push(productToAdd);
    }


    localStorage.setItem(cartName, JSON.stringify(currentCart));
}
addToCart();


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage return strings, so you can't do:

```
currentCart[itemIndex].quantity += productToAdd.quantity;
```

You need to parse the localStorage value eg:

```
const qty = parseInt(currentCart[itemIndex].quantity);
currentCart[itemIndex].quantity = qty + productToAdd.quantity;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that was really helpfull
Have a nice day ! :-P